# How to change the default rectangular view for a:hover background image?

Tags: css

For instance,

```
a:hover {
    color: black;
    background:url("images/nav-hm.png");
}
```

The background image displayed upon hover is always enclosed in a rectangular box around the link even though the image isn't rectangular .

Is there a way to remove the rectangular box enclosure ?

Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE**

What I intent to use for the background image - [Image](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/Untitled-2-1.png)
The image is actually a cropped out image of a cloud. I want the cloud to show fully upon hover.

Even after setting the width and height of the background image to match, it doesn't show fully. This is what is shown.
[Image2](http://i418.photobucket.com/albums/pp270/ravenoz_bucket/zzzzzzzzzzz.png)

Code after adjusting width and height to match actual image used

```
a:hover {
  color: black;
  background:url("images/Untitled-2-2.png");
  width:337px;
  height:292px;
  }
```

Comment: Could you share a live demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or post an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Posted images, hopefully it makes things clearer =)

Answer (score 0):

If the `a` element is rectangular (or rectangular-ish, think of how it could wrap over multiple lines) then its background is rectangular. Depending on what shape you're after you could alter its appearence with `border-radius`, or could opt-in for some specific rendering of a `text-shadow` instead. Would help if you provided a mockup of you're trying to accomplish.

Oh, by the way. The image *is* rectangular :) even if some areas are fully transparent, bitmaps, or at least the ones used on the web, cannot have a different shape.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of complete cross browser border radius

```
a{
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
  width:337px;
  height:292px;
}


a:hover {
  color: black;
  background:url("images/Untitled-2-2.png");
 /* Add border radius */    
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```